# Problems with view containing group_contact

Tags: mysql, view, group-concat

I have a view, but when I use it in select the results differs depending on the where clause:

```
select * from cases_keywords2 ck where case_id = 10732 or case_id = 10733 or case_id = 10740`
```

Returns:

| case_id | keywords_ids | keywords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10732 | 1,52,118 | sanity,automated,alm |
| 10733 |  |  |
| 10740 | 1 | sanity |

but

```
select * from cases_keywords2 ck where case_id = 10733 or case_id = 10740
```

returns:

| case_id | keywords_ids | keywords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10733 |  |  |
| 10740 | 118 | alm |

Note the changed value for case_id=10740.
The cases_keywords2 view is defined by this select:

```
select
    `c`.`id` AS `case_id`,
    coalesce(group_concat(`t`.`id` separator ','), '') AS `keyword_ids`,
    coalesce(group_concat(`t`.`keyword` separator ','), '') AS `keywords`
from
    (`synergy`.`case` `c`
left join (
    select
        `ck`.`case_id` AS `case_id`,
        `k`.`id` AS `id`,
        `k`.`keyword` AS `keyword`
    from
        (`synergy`.`case_has_keyword` `ck`
    join `synergy`.`keyword` `k` on
        ((`ck`.`keyword_id` = `k`.`id`)))) `t` on
    ((`c`.`id` = `t`.`case_id`)))
group by `c`.`id`;
```

I've tried to replace the view by it's source and remove the `group by` and I've got expected result:

```
select
    `c`.`id` AS `case_id`,t.id,t.keyword
from
    (`synergy`.`case` `c`
left join (
    select
        `ck`.`case_id` AS `case_id`,
        `k`.`id` AS `id`,
        `k`.`keyword` AS `keyword`
    from
        (`synergy`.`case_has_keyword` `ck`
    join `synergy`.`keyword` `k` on
        ((`ck`.`keyword_id` = `k`.`id`)))) `t` on
    ((`c`.`id` = `t`.`case_id`)))
where c.id = 10732 or c.id = 10733 or c.id = 10740;
```

| case_id | id | keyword |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10732 | 1 | sanity |
| 10732 | 52 | automated |
| 10732 | 118 | alm |
| 10733 |  |  |
| 10740 | 118 | alm |

But after adding back `group by` the wrong value is still there:

```
select
    `c`.`id` AS `case_id`,
    coalesce(group_concat(`t`.`id` separator ','), '') AS `keyword_ids`,
    coalesce(group_concat(`t`.`keyword` separator ','), '') AS `keywords`
from
    (`synergy`.`case` `c`
left join (
    select
        `ck`.`case_id` AS `case_id`,
        `k`.`id` AS `id`,
        `k`.`keyword` AS `keyword`
    from
        (`synergy`.`case_has_keyword` `ck`
    join `synergy`.`keyword` `k` on
        ((`ck`.`keyword_id` = `k`.`id`)))) `t` on
    ((`c`.`id` = `t`.`case_id`)))
where c.id = 10732 or c.id = 10733 or c.id = 10740
group by `c`.`id`;
```

| case_id | keywords_ids | keywords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10732 | 1,52,118 | sanity,automated,alm |
| 10733 |  |  |
| 10740 | 1 | sanity |

Is there a way how to prevent interaction between the view and the `where` clause? Or can `group_concat` call be modified to get the expected result?

Thanks!

Edited: reproducible with dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=20822073b30d962065bcd7b8294824fe

Comment: This seems like a bug in version 8.0.27: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33c28933819b4eb9ee5b193a4b970f29. In version 8.0.12 it works fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Y9gSFzZ14s2VgjZvBZjgP/0 and in previous version 5.7.35 also fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=33c28933819b4eb9ee5b193a4b970f29

Comment: As commented, it seems like a bug in the [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) function. As a workaround you can `... group by c.id, t.case_id ...` or use a subquery to get the expected result.

Comment: I've reported it to the mysql team (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107537), but in the latest version 8.0.29 the problem is already fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

use Mysql 8.0.29+

or

change 'group by c.id' to 'group by c.id, t.case_id'

Thanks @wchiquito